# Building a solution with Shared Project fails on references errors

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin-test-cloud

I have solution with UI Tests for my mobile applications in Xamarin.

This is setup:

- MyApp.iOS - application for iOS
- MyApp.Android - application for Android
- MyApp.UITests.iOS - where is only reference to iOS project and shared library
- MyApp.UITests.Android - where is only reference to Android project and shared library
- MyApp.UITests.SharedLibrary - with all test cases

When I am building this in MSBuild I have many errors with:

> /Users/vstsagent/MyApp.UITests.SharedLibrary/...: error CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name `Xamarin' could not be found.

It looks like problem is compilation of my SharedLibrary project.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Solution structure including the References for each Project?

Comment: @MarcoK sure, I will do this.

Comment: Is your SharedLibrary a PCL or a literal Shared Project type?

Comment: literal Shared Project